# Can we write intent-filter in java code as well ?? Give reason why and how?

Tags: android

I have read the above mention question on skillgun but didn't found any satisfied description. Kindly give some valid reasons for it

Comment: Yes. What would you like to do with such `IntentFilter`?

Comment: any kind of task, i am using it in xml actually i need some idea how to use intent-filter inside a java class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new IntentFilter with an action:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("action");
```

Add a new action to the IntentFilter:

```
filter.addAction("action");
```

Here is the document: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html

You need to create an IntentFilter in code, if you want to register a BroadcastReceiver in code.

Comment: Thanx, i got an idea :)